# d3.js range selector not filtering tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I have modified couple of `d3.js` demo projects to meet my requirement. But facing few problems.Here is the `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/fmtygLfv/
With range selector my `tooltips` are not filtering they are staying same as it is. Also the `tooltips` are not placed properly and I cant put any `special character` in my `X-axis` like currently it is `0.1` to `1.0` but `0.0-0.1 to 0.9-1.0` is not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, for the scatter plot, you are appending to the `svg`. You need to append to the same area the path is created at. So instead of (on line 110) :

```
svg.selectAll("dot")
```

Do :

```
focus.selectAll("dot")
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/fmtygLfv/2/

As for the dots (tooltips). I have put the creation of the dots in a function like so :

```
// Add the scatterplot

 function addScatter(){

        focus.selectAll(".dot").data(data)          
        .enter().append("circle").attr('class','dot')                               
        .attr("r", 5)       
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.price); })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(d.date + "<br/>"  + d.price)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
        }
addScatter()
```

Instantiated it straight away. Now this can be used when you brush. Updated brush :

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  focus.selectAll(".dot").remove()  ; //remove current dots
  addScatter()
}
```

Notice before I call `addScatter` I delete the dots that are already there. This works fine now.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/fmtygLfv/5/

As for your tick values. Look at this example : [D3 - using strings for axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772115/d3-using-strings-for-axis-ticks)

At the moment you data shows dates ranging from 0.2 - 1.0. They are single values and not themselves ranges.

So if your data looked like this :

```
var data =  [{ "date":"0.1-0.2",  "price":394.46}, 
  { "date":"0.2-0.3",  "price":1366.42}, 
  { "date":"0.3-0.4",  "price":1498.58}, 
  { "date":"0.4-0.5",  "price":1452.43},//and so on
```

You could use, from the example above, the tick values like so :

```
.tickFormat(function(d, i){
    return d.date; // this will return (if data is edited) 0.1-0.2, 0.2-0.3 and so on
})
```

This would mean editing your data.

Comment: Make sense @thisOneGuy

Comment: @DibyenduDutta updated. think there was one more problem you had

Comment: Your final problem with the special characters, I am unsure on why you would want to do this ? The axis is there to show data at the point, you can't have both 0.9 and 1.0 at the same point :/

Comment: Yes @thisOneGuy . Actually my `X-axis` values will be range , it is how the data is designed.And i am trying to put the same in `X-axis`

Comment: added to answer. You will have to edit your data to change the tick format as described in my updated answer

Comment: `var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(function(d, i){
    return d.date; 
}) ` this is correct ?

Comment: I think we have to modify how we are generating range also . like `x=d3.scale.linear()` should be `d3.scale.ordinal()` right ?

Comment: the ticks are being shown exactly how your data is. As of now your data is getting interpreted as integers, you want it to be, for example, 0.1-0.2, this is not an integer but a string. So to do this your data must be changed. For example, look at this bar chart : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304, the data shows letters a-z with values. The ticks are instantiated like so : x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; })); Do you understand ?

Comment: Yes I do understand I have to change my data. What I am asking here is we have to modify how we are generating range also . like x=d3.scale.linear() should be d3.scale.ordinal() right ?

Comment: Yes as you are using strings